# Use scenarios for complex data type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As we all know in python, there is one type of data - complex . I read the doc and then cannot find the use case, when to use it, and then what's its characters?

```
a = 20
b = 328
c = complex(a, b)
print(type(c))
```

Comment: Do you want to know what [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) are?

Comment: The complex numbers form what is known as a field.  You can add them, subtract them, negate them, multiply them, divide them, etc.  You can create them as shown in your example, and you can also use complex literals, e.g. `3j`, or `(2+7j)`, etc.

Comment: I want to know its usage case in the real project..... Your answer is same as the doc from standard website about the python, but it never tells its usage scene...When to use it. and its character.. @TomKarzes

Comment: @mozway I just want to know its use case in the real project.

Comment: @MarcSteven it's... for when you need to use a complex number. You keep mentioning "the real project", what project are you talking about?'

Comment: It's not really clear what kind of answer you expect other than that it is used to represent complex numbers in projects that need complex numbers.

Comment: @blackbrandt U can show an real example...... for example??

Comment: For example, complex numbers can represent positions and rotations in a 2D plane. ``1+0j`` is "right", ``1j`` is "up". But they show up all over the place with non-trivial math.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I just want to know ' Use scenarios for complex data' in python

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you so much, haha  I never did this project , so I never use the data type, so today I want to know it completely... Perhaps the doc needs to make it clear to let developer understand why using it? haha

Comment: @Marc complex numbers are used everywhere, math, physics… it could take several books to detail all uses… check the [Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Applications) section in my first link.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not in the scope of SO

Comment: @MarcSteven Asking what the use case for complex number is isn't much different from asking what the use case for real numbers is.  They are used in electrical engineering, many branches of applied math, pure math, physics, etc.  Take a course in complex analysis if you want to understand the major theorems involving complex numbers.  In any case, this question really has nothing to do with Python.  Python is merely one language out of many that supports complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex data types are used for advanced calculation in Electronics and applied or astrophysics or such type, just like we use complex numbers in the real world.
Complex numbers are used in electronics and electromagnetism. A single complex number puts together two real quantities, making the numbers easier to work with. For example, in electronics, the state of a circuit element is defined by the voltage (V) and the current (I).

In python, some libraries are used these things like:-

1. SkiDL
2. PySpice
3. Numpy
   ...etc

Comment: I found your answer is clear, based on the doc only tell you what the complex data type is , but never told you when to use it clearly... @sohail